# Select A Value From A Row Where A Column Equals Something

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

As you see in the picture below, I have a work sheet that has some columns.

[image]

I want summation of column G where column C equals to Australia, and then put the result in another sheet field. (picture blow)

[image]

I couldn't find a proper way for this purpose, So I had to write the numbers in fields with pink background manually, while numbers in this column should be taken from the other sheet (the blue sheet).
How can I say "select summation of column G in first sheet where country is Australia and put the result in other sheet?"

Comment: Look into SUMIF()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:
`=SUMIF(Sheet1!C:C,B2,Sheet1!G:G)`

Sheet1 is the sheet where you have details
C the column of Country in Sheet1
B2 where you have the country in the summary sheet
G the column that you want to sum for country=B2
and you can drag the formula down

For information about Sumif click on [Sumif Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)